# I am facing ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: "" when executing below query

Tags: hibernate

I am facing ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: "" when executing below query.

Getting parameters in Java

```
Integer Id_systemUser = systemUser.getId();
Integer userid = systemUser.getId();
```

MyQuery

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(
                    "SELECT (SELECT count(*)  FROM ResponseTable Where  timedate BETWEEN :sentDate and :enddate  and Id_systemUser=:Id_systemUser ) AS"
                            + "receivecount,(SELECT count(*)  FROM ResponseTable Where  timedate BETWEEN :sentDate and :enddate  and Id_systemUser=:Id_systemUser and processCompletetime IS NOT NULL ) AS processcount,"
                            + "(select SUM(CAST(msg_cost AS DECIMAL(9,2))) from sql_reciept_sms where  dlr_mask='31' and time BETWEEN :sentDate and :enddate  and userid=:userid) AS loadedcount,(select SUM(CAST(msg_cost AS DECIMAL(9,2)))"
                            + " from sql_reciept_sms where dlr_mask_smsc_sub='8'  and time BETWEEN :sentDate and :enddate  and userid=:userid) AS sentcount,(select SUM(CAST(msg_cost AS DECIMAL(9,2))) from sql_reciept_sms where time BETWEEN "
                            + ":sentDate and :enddate and userid=:userid and dlr_mask_del_failure='2') AS failprocesscount,(select SUM(CAST(msg_cost AS DECIMAL(9,2))) from sql_reciept_sms where dlr_mask_del_success='1' and time BETWEEN :sentDate"
                            + " and :enddate  and userid=:userid) AS delicount,(select SUM(CAST(msg_cost AS DECIMAL(9,2))) from sql_reciept_sms where dlr_mask_smsc_rej='16' and time BETWEEN :sentDate and :enddate  and userid=:userid) AS "
                            + "rejcount,(select SUM(CAST(msg_cost AS DECIMAL(9,2))) from sql_reciept_sms where  dlr_mask_smsc_sub='8' and dlr_mask_smsc_rej IS NULL and dlr_mask_del_failure IS NULL and dlr_mask_del_success IS NULL "
                            + "and time BETWEEN :sentDate and :enddate  and userid=:userid) AS nodelrec,(select SUM(CAST(msg_cost AS DECIMAL(9,2))) from sql_reciept_sms where  dlr_mask='31' and dlr_mask_smsc_rej "
                            + "IS NULL and dlr_mask_del_failure IS NULL and dlr_mask_del_success IS NULL and dlr_mask_smsc_sub IS NULL and time BETWEEN :sentDate and :enddate  and userid=:userid and binfo IS NULL) AS quatmno,"
                            + "(SELECT count(*) from sql_reciept_sms where time BETWEEN :sentDate and :enddate  and userid=:userid and binfo<>'' and dlr_mask_smsc_rej IS NULL and dlr_mask_del_failure IS NULL and dlr_mask_del_success "
                            + "IS NULL and dlr_mask_smsc_sub IS NULL) as failprocess,(Select SUM(CAST(msg_cost AS DECIMAL(9,2))) from sql_reciept_sms where time BETWEEN :sentDate and :enddate and dlr_mask_del_success='1' and dlr_mask_smsc_sub IS"
                            + " NULL and userid=:userid)   as nosenbdel,(Select SUM(CAST(msg_cost AS DECIMAL(9,2))) from sql_reciept_sms where  time BETWEEN :sentDate and :enddate and dlr_mask_del_failure='2' and dlr_mask_smsc_sub IS NULL "
                            + "and userid=:userid) as nosenbfail");
```

Adding parameters

```
query.setParameter("Id_systemUser", (int) Id_systemUser);
query.setParameter("userid", (int) userid);
query.setParameter("sentDate", sentDate);
query.setParameter("enddate", enddate);
```

While executing

```
query.getResultList()
```

Error

```
2020-Apr-07 18 WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:127 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22P02
2020-Apr-07 18 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:129 - ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""
```

EDIT 1 : 
[image]
   These are the values that are not 1 .

The issue is with 3rd subquery

```
(SELECT Sum(Cast(msg_cost AS DECIMAL(9, 2))) 
        FROM   sql_reciept_sms 
        WHERE  dlr_mask = '31' 
               AND time BETWEEN 'Wed Apr 01 00:00:00 SAST 2020' AND 
                                'Fri Apr 10 00:00:00 SAST 2020' 
               AND userid = '14630824')             AS loadedcount,
```

Comment: It must be that you are getting input string "" instead of value in a variable defined for numeric while setting query. Try to log variables and check once.

Comment: manikanta nvsr Edited question for your comment

Comment: Is it possible for you to add some more context to the code to understand the flow?

Comment: Are you sure that userid or dlr_mask is String? if not, give the value without single quotes.

Comment: Yes the issue is with Sum(Cast(msg_cost AS DECIMAL(9, 2))) i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, I am guessing it must be wrong syntax while handling empty Strings or null values. Try using the following cast Syntax:

Use the following syntax:

```
Sum(coalesce(cast(nullif(msg_cost ,'') as DECIMAL(9,2)),0))
```

Comment: Post this sum query i am getting "Parameter with that name [sentDate ] did not exist"

Comment: That means, the previous error got resolved. Now, this is another error you ought to resolve. So above answer resolved your question.